# Azure Policy ARM template - wildcard in resource name

Tags: arrays, json, azure, azure-resource-manager, policy

I'm building a policy assignment that needs to exclude specific resource group according to their name. Resource groups starting with "Atlanta" should be excluded.
An array would not suffice. Is creating a parameter or variable with wildcard "Atlanta*" possible or how do I achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this in the portal.  I think your best option though not ideal is to use PowerShell/CLI to programmatically assign this policy to the RG's you wish.  The logic inside your PowerShell/CLI can exclude the "Atlanta" RG's.

```
# Get a reference to the resource group that is the scope of the assignment
$rg = Get-AzResourceGroup -Name '<resourceGroupName>'

# Get a reference to the built-in policy definition to assign
$definition = Get-AzPolicyDefinition | Where-Object { $_.Properties.DisplayName -eq 'Audit VMs that do not use managed disks' }

# Create the policy assignment with the built-in definition against your resource group
New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name 'audit-vm-manageddisks' -DisplayName 'Audit VMs without managed disks Assignment' -Scope $rg.ResourceId -PolicyDefinition $definition
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/assign-policy-powershell

Comment: I ended up excluding Atlanta* in a custom policy definition instead